# XAML converter binding for multiple properties

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to display some text in a Xamarin forms ListView grid, based on the comparison of 2 date properties. I have a converter to compare the dates and return a string. What I am trying to do (without success) is pass the entire object to the converter.

XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <converters1:CancelConverter x:Key="CancelConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
...
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CancelConverter}}" />
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Converter:

```
public class CancelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Schedule schedule = ((Schedule)value);
        DateTime date1 = schedule.ProposedCollectionDate;
        DateTime date2 = schedule.OrderDate;
        if (date1.CompareTo(date2) < 0)
        {
            return "Cancel this order";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the converter, value is null. How can I pass the object to the Converter, instead of just a single property of the object?

Comment: Schedule is a property of list item or Item itself?

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown looks good to me, but there may be something bad in what you've hidden. I can't tell, but are you properly setting the binding context of the `ListView` i.e. are you setting the `ItemsSource` property? From the information you've given, you should be setting it to something like an `ObservableCollection<Schedule>` or `IEnumerable<Schedule>` and then each item in the `ListView` would have a `Schedule` as its binding context and it would make its way into the value converter happily.

Comment: The ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableRangeCollection<Schedule>. I have no problems if I try to pass a single property of the Schedule object to the converter, I can access that, i.e. Binding SomeProperty. It is Binding . which is not working.

Comment: Hmmm that's frustrating, because I know for sure this is possible because I've done it several times and I'm looking right at a couple of those times right now.

When you say it is or is not working, do you mean a breakpoint at the first line in the converter shows `value` to be null or not null or are you using some other criteria?

Comment: value is null when I use Binding . (i.e. binding to the object). Binding to an object property works as expected.

Comment: @ardmark If you're still having the problem I'd be willing to take another look if there's any way you can share more code in a simple example that recreates the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think I will need to look for another solution as I have to get this finished now so I can move on with the project.